# Does wait_until work differently in main thread wrt not main one? c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, condition-variable

Executing the same code in main thread wrt a separate one,the condition variable behaves differently

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
void waits()
{
    std::mutex mCvMtx;
    std::condition_variable mCondVar;

   auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mCvMtx);
    if(mCondVar.wait_until(lk, now+ 3*1000ms) ==  cv_status::timeout)
    {
        cout << "Fire";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Condition variable notified ";
    }
    now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
}

int main()
{

     std::thread t1(waits);
     t1.join(); 

    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main()
{
     std::mutex mCvMtx;
    std::condition_variable mCondVar;

   auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mCvMtx);
    if(mCondVar.wait_until(lk, now+ 3*1000ms) ==  cv_status::timeout)
    {
        cout << "Fire";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Condition variable notified ";
    }
    now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    return 0;
}
```

I cannot understand why in the first example the output results in "Fire" (so the cv was not notified and it waits the time I indicated) while in the second case where I execute the same code in the main thread, the output results in "Condition variable notified", without wait any seconds.

Do you have any explanantion? thanks

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use `system_clock` to *measure* time, prefer `steady_clock` instead (system clock can get adjusted, e. g. being updated via ntp).

Answer (score 4):

It's because of [spurious wakeups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup)

> Spurious wakeup describes a complication in the use of condition
>   variables as provided by certain multithreading APIs such as POSIX
>   Threads and the Windows API.
>
> Even after a condition variable appears to have been signaled from a
>   waiting thread's point of view, the condition that was awaited may
>   still be false. One of the reasons for this is a spurious wakeup; that
>   is, a thread might be awoken from its waiting state even though no
>   thread signaled the condition variable. For correctness it is
>   necessary, then, to verify that the condition is indeed true after the
>   thread has finished waiting. Because spurious wakeup can happen
>   repeatedly, this is achieved by waiting inside a loop that terminates
>   when the condition is true

Further read:

[C++ Core Guidelines: Be Aware of the Traps of Condition Variables](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-be-aware-of-the-traps-of-condition-variables)

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that but can that be systematic? I mean, i run that codes at least 10 times each and the result was always the same (no spurious wake up in the previous case and always in the seconds)....the explanation I gave myself was that maybe this spurious wake up is really systematic and the creation of a thread requires the right amount of time do let it pass before i enter in the wait condition.....but i dont know if that makes sense at all. Can you agree with my theory?
ps.thanks for the answer

Comment: @SeriouslLancerl the mechanisms of and all the factors that influence spurious wakeups are very complex and way above my pay grade. Only an expert with experience in low level system architecture, synchronization mechanisms and compiler implementation can answer that.

Answer (score 0):

A condition variable is merely a notification mechanism with no state, so that notifications get lost when there are no waiters and spurious wake-ups unblock it when no notification was emitted.

You must wait for a change in a shared state. E.g.:

```
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable c;

// Only ever read or write shared_state when the mutex is locked.
// Otherwise race conditions create a deadlock.
bool shared_state = false;

// Waiting thread.
void wait() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
    while(!shared_state) // Also handles spurious wake ups.
        c.wait(l);
    // shared_state is true, mutex is locked.
}

// Notifying thread.
void wait() {
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
        shared_state = true;
    }
    c.notify_one();
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, there's a wait function with a predicate as additional parameter doing the same: `c.wait(l, []() { return shared_state; });`

Comment: @Aconcagua It is easy to make things bigger and more complicated. It is hard to make them any better. Think about the carbon footprint, otherwise unnecessary, that goes into creating a unique lambda class, lambda object of that class and the optimizer optimizing it away.

Comment: With such a simple predicate I'd assume the compiler optimising any overhead away again... That said, I just wanted to show up that another way *exists* ('alternatively'), without any qualification if better or worse, leaving this to the readers...